# ROOT(cern) FILE reading+TGraph works ok, but TGraphErrors doesnt want

Tags: c++, root-framework

The problem is next:
I had read my data from a file to the array. Graph plotting works without any problem. But TGraphErrors doesnt want to do anything. Root says

> Error: Can't call
>   TGraphErrors::SetPoint(i,Data[0][i],Data[1][i],Data[2][i],Data[2][i])
>   in current scope plot2.C:85: Possible candidates are... (in
>   TGraphErrors) (in TGraph)
>   /usr/local/Cellar/root/5.34.26/lib/root/libHist.so  -1:-1   0 public:
>   virtual void TGraph::SetPoint(Int_t i,Double_t x,Double_t y);
>   *** Interpreter error recovered ***"

Code is below:

```
    void plot2(char* fin1){
    const int VAR_N=20,NPOINTS=10000;
    Double_t Data[VAR_N][NPOINTS];
   int counts,N1;
   float E,E1,dE;
   FILE* fin12;
    printf("%s \n",fin1);
    fin12 = fopen(fin1,"r");
      if (fin12 == NULL){
        printf("Can't open input file: %s !\n",fin1);
    }
    else{
        counts=0; 
        while (!feof(fin12)) {
            fscanf(fin12, "%f %f %f \n",&E,&E1,&dE);
            printf("%f %f %f \n",E,E1,dE);
                Data[0][counts] =   E;
                Data[1][counts] =   E1;
                Data[2][counts] =   dE;  }
        N1=counts;
        printf("NP1=%d ",N1);
        fclose(fin12);
    }
   TGraph* V_Graph = new TGraph(N1);
    TGraphErrors* V_GraphErrors = new TGraphErrors(N1);
    for(int i=0;i<N1;i++){
       V_Graph->SetPoint(i,Data[0][i],Data[1][i]);
     } 
   for(int i=0;i<N1;i++){
   V_GraphErrors->SetPoint(i,Data[0][i],Data[1][i],Data[2][i],Data[2][i]);
  }

TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1", "c1", 1200, 1000);
  c1->cd(1);
   TString VName="+Errors";
   V_Graph->SetTitle(VName);
   V_Graph->SetMarkerStyle(21);
   V_Graph->SetMarkerSize(1);
   V_Graph->SetMarkerColor(kBlue);
    V_Graph->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("x");
    V_Graph->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("y");
    V_Graph->GetXaxis()->SetLimits(4.,25.);
    V_Graph->GetYaxis()->SetRangeUser(10.,80.);
    V_Graph->Draw("APL");

    V_GraphErrors->SetMarkerStyle(21);
    V_GraphErrors->SetMarkerSize(1);
    V_GraphErrors->SetMarkerColor(kGreen);
    //V_Graph->GetXaxis()->SetLimits(4.,11.);
    //V_Graph->GetYaxis()->SetRangeUser(45.,80.);
    V_GraphErrors->Draw("C*");
}
```

I'm new in root-using.Probably i did smthg stupid and didnt notice it. So what i did wrong?
Thank you in advance
Olka

Comment: Maybe compile the code with a c++ compiler, and hope it will yield a more useful error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no `SetPointError` method with the signature you are trying to use `(int, Double_t, Double_t, Double_t, Double_t)`. To set the errors you should use the `SetPointError(Double_t ex, Double_t ey)` method. For example, in your code above you would do something like:

```
V_GraphErrors->SetPoint(i,Data[0][i],Data[1][i]]);
V_GraphErrors->SetPointError(i,Data[2][i],Data[2][i]);
```

Although it would probably be easier to pass the arrys directly in the constructor:

```
V_GraphErrors(N1, Data[0], Data[1], Data[2], Data[2]);
```

Btw, this will set the x and y errors to be identical. I'm not sure if this is what you intended.

See https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TGraphErrors.html for details of the methods available in TGraphErrors

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I made changes which you suggested. Now root says only

//Error: Can't call TGraphErrors::SetPointErrors(i,Data[2][i],Data[3][i]) in current scope plot2.C:92:
Possible candidates are...
(in TGraphErrors)
(in TGraph)///

The same errors for x and y in this example because it's test, in reality i need only dy.  The main point is to understand why it doesnt want to work for me. to be honest i'm very bad in programming. and not all explanations on the current manual(at official webpages) are understandable for me